# How do I make multiple inputs in a form appear as a select option value on different form on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

This is my very first question on stack overflow, so please be patient with me.

I have created a form to be filled out by the user, there's one select box (to choose your country) and three input fields (zip code, city and street address).

Now, when submitting this form (on button click), I want this information to be displayed as a single option value in the select box in my other form.

Can someone help me? I've tried to look it up everywhere but I can't find any answers.

Here's the HTML.erb for the first form the user have to fill out:

```
<div id="custom-form-field-wrapper">
      <h2>Leveringsadresse</h2>
      <a id="toggle-address-button"> Add address </a>
      <div class="custom-form-field" id="address-form-field">
      <%= render 'addresses/form' %>
      <a id="cancel-address-button"> Cancel </a>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-form-field" id="order-form-field">
      <%= render 'form', order: @order %>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here's the rendered code for the **address form:**

```
<%= simple_form_for current_user.addresses.new do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :country, priority: ['Norway'], label: false %>
 <%= f.input :zip_code, :placeholder => 'Postnr', :maxlength => '4', label: false %>
 <%= f.input :city, :placeholder => 'By', label: false %>
 <%= f.input :street_address, :placeholder => "Gateadresse", label: false %>
 <%= f.button :submit, 'Legg til' %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the HTML.erb for the other select form I want the new option value to be displayed:

```
  <%= form_tag orders_path, id: 'payment-form' do %>
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>
  <div class="form-group" id="velg_leveringsadresse">
  <%= select_tag 'address', options_for_select(current_user.addresses.all.collect { |a| [a.full_address, a.id] }), class: 'form-control', prompt: 'Leveringsadresse' %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Firstly, welcome to SO. We can offer you advice and guidance, but we need to see what you have tried so far. Can you update your question with the form in question, along with your attempts to solve the problem (regardless of if it works)?

Comment: May be this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/z1fp0v9a/

Comment: Hi! Thank you, I updated my question now and posted some the code. This is very new to me, I dont know where to start so that's why I dont have any attempts for it.

I'll check out the jsfiddle now.

Comment: @RayonDabre That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.
How can I make the select option to only show one of the inputs? For example, only displaying the street address for the user after submitting the form?

Comment: May be `$(SELECTOR).val()`

Answer (score 1):

Both Rails and Simple form have methods to create selects, checkboxes and radio buttons from an association or a collection of records.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease
- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

---

This is the conventional way to do it:

```
<%= simple_form_for @order, id: 'payment-form' do |f| %>
  #... more fields
  <%= f.association :delivery_address, 
    collection: current_user.addresses, 
    prompt: "Velg leveringsaddresse", 
    label_method:  :street_address
  %>
<% end %>
```

Note that you need to create a relation in your model to back it:

```
class Order
  has_one :delivery_address, class: "Address"
end
```

And a migration to add a column to Order:

```
rails g AddDeleveryAddressToOrder delivery_address:references
```

You can repeat the steps to add a separate billing address.

---

Note that if you intend to have the user do everything asynchronously, IE the user types in addresses in a modal dialog or in some other part of the order#new page you need to refresh the input when the user has created new addresses.

One way to do this would be to do a request for:

```
GET /users/:user_id/addresses.json # Note that you actually have to implement it!
```

First we can add a path to the input to tell it where to fetch data:

```
<%= simple_form_for @order, id: 'payment-form' do |f| %>
  #... more fields
  <%= f.association :delivery_address, 
    collection: current_user.addresses, 
    prompt: "Velg leveringsaddresse", 
    label_method:  :street_address,
    data: {
      path: user_addresses_path(user: current_user)
    }
  %>
<% end %>
```

Then we setup a handler that can fetch the data and render a new set of options.

```
$("#payment-form").on('refresh', function(){
  var $add_select = $(this).find('input[name="order[delivery_address]"]');
  var promise = $.getJSON($add_select.data('path'));
  // transform JSON data to a series of `<option>` elements
  promise.pipe(function(addresses){
    return $.map(addresses, function(address){
      var el = $("<option>"+ address["street_address"] +"</option>");
      el.val(address["id"]);
      return el;
    });
  });
  // replace contents of select with new options
  promise.done(function(options){
    $add_select.empty().append(options);
  });

  return false;
});
```

Note that we are setting up a listenter for a non-standard `refresh` event. You would fire the event when the AJAX handler for `POST /addresses` finishes:

```
$("#address_form").on('submit', function(){
  var $form = $(this);
  var promise = $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray());
  promise.done(function(){
    $("#payment-form").trigger('refresh');
  });
});
```

See [working with javascript in rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) for instructions on how to integrate this with the rails ujs handler.

Comment: An additional remark - don't use `label: false` and placeholders for styling purposes. Its really compromises the accessibility of your app. You can get the same result with CSS.